# ms sql use like statement result in if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @d varchar
set @d = 'No filter'

if (@d like 'No filter')
  BEGIN
    select 'matched'
  end
else
  begin
    select 'not matched'
  end
```

the result of above is always not matched can anybody tell me why and how can I use the like or '=' result in my stored procedure.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your declaration to

```
declare @d varchar(10)
```

Then

```
declare @d varchar(10)

set @d = 'No filter' 

if (@d LIKE 'No filter') 
  BEGIN 
    select 'matched' 
  end 
else 
  begin 
    select 'not matched' 
  end
```

will work.

Please remember that [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is used for pattern matching,

something like

```
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(10)
SET @Val = 'foo bar'
if (@Val LIKE '%foo%') 
  BEGIN 
    select 'matched' 
  end 
else 
  begin 
    select 'not matched' 
  end
```

So in your case you might want to change the code to

```
declare @d varchar(10)
set @d = 'No filter' 

if (@d = 'No filter') 
  BEGIN 
    select 'matched' 
  end 
else 
  begin 
    select 'not matched' 
  end
```

with an "="

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare d as varchar(100) not just varchar, otherwise it just becomes N

```
declare @d varchar
set @d = 'No filter'
```

Should be:

```
declare @d varchar(100)
set @d = 'No filter'
```

Also no need to use LIKE with this you can use =.

Comment: Add print @d or select @d to prove this to yourself.

Comment: +1: Correct - it's good habit to always define data type attributes than assume defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I find `like` operator very useful.

```sql
IF(
      @PLI_Component  =   '' + @ITemID  + '' +'BD'
      OR @PLI_Component  =   '' + @ITemID  + '' +'BD/1'
      OR @PLI_Component  =   '' + @ITemID  + '' +'BD/2'
      OR @PLI_Component  =   '' + @ITemID  + '' +'BD/3'    
      OR @PLI_Component  =   '' + @ITemID  + '' +'BD/4'    
      OR @PLI_Component  =   '' + @ITemID  + '' +'BD/5'    
)
```

can be replaced

by only one line which is

```
@PLI_Component  LIKE    @ITemID   +'BD'
```

Answer (score 0):

little workaround to use like in if-statement (MSSQL)

```
if (SELECT CASE WHEN @value like '%Searchtext%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
  print 'Yes'
else
  print 'No'
```